# Can a temperature be described as unusual or abnormal?

Tags: word-choice

Can a temperature be described as unusual or abnormal?
I'm trying to figure a way to say that the temperature is not within its normal range.

Answer (score 2):

"Unusually high temperatures have been measured in..."

"Abnormally high temperatures have been measured in..."

Both are pretty synonymous and they're both linguistically correct.